# what is BaseUser and BaseUserAdmin in django

Tags: django, django-models

what is BaseUser in django . why is it used?

What role does it play during the creation of custom user model and why attributes it present ?

Answer (score 0):

`BaseUser` is base class for every Django user class. Also, `BaseUerAdmin` is inherited from `BaseUser`.